# How to fix Netbeans 8.0 not detecting Java ME

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-8, platform

I am trying to set up NetBeans 8.0 for development in Java ME (I know this is legacy software, but it is the only software I know of that supports Java ME), however, NetBeans will not detect my Java ME platform in the platform manager any time I try to load it. You can view this error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvLfy.png). My version of Java
is 1.8.0_201. The log from the Java ME SDK reads:

[2019-02-16 09:20:12.444]   INFO - lkit.bootstrap.DeployerManager - Registering custom property editors 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.463]   INFO - me.toolkit.bootstrap.Namespace - Starting batch, base module object-server 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.476]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Consolidating dependencies... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.476]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Consolidated dependencies... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.477]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Calculating order... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.477]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Calculated order 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.494]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Initializing objects... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.495]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Applying I18N 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.495]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Initialized objects 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.495]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Calling create() methods... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.496]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Calling start() methods... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.503]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Objects started 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.506]   INFO - me.toolkit.bootstrap.Namespace - Starting batch, base module process/device-manager 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.536]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Consolidating dependencies... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.537]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Consolidated dependencies... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.537]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Calculating order... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.538]   INFO - bootstrap.ObjectGraphProcessor - Calculated order 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.865]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Initializing objects... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.914]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Applying I18N 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.915]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Initialized objects 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.915]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Calling create() methods... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.919]   INFO - un.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch - Calling start() methods... 
[2019-02-16 09:20:12.959]  ERROR - sun.kvem.tools.http.HttpServer - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:329)
    at com.sun.kvem.tools.http.HttpServer.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.kvem.tools.http.HttpServer.run(Unknown Source)

I've tried many answers to this on many forums including this one, but none of them have worked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Re _"NetBeans fails to recognize my Java ME platform"_, you need to be much more specific on what you are doing, and the exact error that you get from NetBeans. What exactly does _"fails to recognize"_ mean?

Comment: @skomisa Thank you for the feedback. Please look at the revised question.

Comment: [1] In your screenshot there is a message: _"...See userdir\javame-sdk\x.x\log\device-manager.log for more details"_, where _"x.x"_ is probably _"8.0"_ in your case. You can open that file in any text editor. [2] Please repeat the attempt to add the Java ME platform. It will fail again, but update your question with **only** the new content written to that log as a result of the new attempt. [3] Also, update your question with the **exact** version/update of Java that you are using to run NetBeans 8.0. You can get that information from **Help > About**.

Comment: @skomisa I added my version of Java to my question, however, my folder with the SDK is called "Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.0" and it has no .log files in it.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place for the log file, and its location has nothing to do with folder "Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.0". It is in a folder named _log_ somewhere under your _{userdir}_ (i.e. in a folder corresponding to your username), which itself is probably under the folder named _C:\Users_.

Comment: @skomisa Thanks. Added the log into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not trivial to fix, and this is not a solution - it is more of an update for your problem since it is is too large for a comment:

First note that the cause of the failure to add Java ME as a platform within NetBeans is shown in the stack trace: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`.

Oracle mention the possibility of getting this exception in many places in their *Java ME* documentation. [For example](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/8.2/sdk-dev-guide/devices.htm#CHDEDFHH):

> 7.2.1 Troubleshooting Device Connection Issues
>
> If the IP address of a device with a running Java ME Embedded runtime instance is not
>   available in the corresponding drop-down list when adding a device
>   connection, see the Device Manager log file. It is located under logs
>   in the Oracle Java ME SDK configuration directory.
>
> The Device Connection log file (device-manager.log) contains errors,
>   warnings, and informational events that you can review in order to
>   find the cause of the problem. The following are some of the common
>   messages that you may encounter:
>
> **WARN - .vmagent.proxy.DeviceDetection - UDP device detection failed
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind**
>
> **Cause:** The device detection ports are used by another application on the host
>   computer. By default, these ports are 55208 and 55209.
>
> **Action:** The best solution is to stop the application that uses these ports or
>   configure it to use different ports. Alternatively, you can configure the device and 
>   Device Manager to use different ports as follows:
>
> 1. Change the ports specified by the
>      proxy.udp_device_detection_request_port and
>      proxy.udp_device_detection_response_port properties in
>      jwc_properties.ini on the device.
> 2. Create a file named proxyOptions.txt under toolkit-lib/lib in the
>      Oracle Java ME SDK installation directory and add the following line
>      to it:
>
> `-bcastports <request> <response>`
>
> The `<request>` and `<response>` port numbers must match those specified in the device properties (see Step > 1).

Since the default ports used by Device Manager are 55208 and 55209 you can check whether those ports are already being used:

- Open a **Command Prompt** window.
- Submit `netstat -aon | findstr 55208` and `netstat -aon | findstr 55209`.

If the two calls to `netstat` return nothing then the ports are available. Otherwise those ports are already in use and you need to find out why, by checking the PIDs that are displayed for the ports in use.

Alternatively, just assign different port numbers, as described in Oracle's documentation shown above. If you are going to do that, first verify that the new port numbers are available using `netstat`. For example, if you want to use port 55210, call `netstat -aon | findstr 55210`. If no other process is using that port then `netstat` will return nothing.

---

**Update:**

The following approach worked for me:

- Select **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**
- Click the **Add Platform...** button and select radio button **Custom Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator** and click **Next >**.
- Click the Browse... button and navigate to your Java ME folder (e.g. "...\Java_ME_platform_SDK_8.0").
- Click **Next >** then **Next >** then **Finish**.

  [image: JavaME]

Comment: I tried `netstat -aon | findstr 55208` and `netstat -aon | findstr 55209` in the command prompt and it showed blank. I decided to change the properties you mentioned in the jwc_properties.ini file. I found neither in the file. I did, however, find two properties called `proxy.client_connection_port = 2200` and `proxy.server_connection_port = 2201`. I changed them to 5000 and 5001 and checked them in the command prompt. The progress bar actually got to 50% but then it failed to detect the platform again for the same reason.

Comment: I just also noticed that the version of Java ME in the .javame-sdk folder is 8.3, but the platform version is 8.0, if that helps.

Comment: I don't think changing the ports you specified helped or hurt, but I'd be inclined to undo that change since Oracle don't mention that. However, if `udp_device_detection_request_port` and `udp_device_detection_response_port` don't currently exist in `jwc_properties.ini` you could try adding them with non-default values, and then trying  _Add Platform..._ again. Not sure what to make of the 8.0 vs. 8.3 issue....you only have a single version of Java ME on your machine, right?

Comment: No, I have 8.3, 8.0, and 3.4 installed because I was trying to see if I could use different versions of Java ME and get different results. Adding those parameters in the `jwc_properties.ini` didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: OK. [1] After you do **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform**  which _platform type_ do you select? [2] After selecting the _platform type_ and clicking **Next>**, how many Java ME platform folders do you add/check in the list titled _"Select Platforms to Detect"_? Do you add/check all three (i.e. 8.0, 8.3, 3.4)? If so, perhaps just try adding only one of them instead, to see if that prevents the **BindException**?

Comment: I choose the Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator and only select 8.0.

Comment: OK. I have just successfully added Java ME 8.0 as a platform on NetBeans 8.2. What worked for me was to select the option _**Custom** Java ME CLDC Plaform Emulator_ instead of _Java ME CLDC Plaform Emulator_ (even though I allowed all settings to default apart from specifying the **Platform Home** field). Can you try that?

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Can you put that as an answer so I can mark it as correct for other people to see?

Comment: Cool. I updated my answer. You should be able to add your other ME platforms in the same manner.