# Java ME SDK platform detection failure - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, netbeans-8

I am trying to set up the Java ME 8 development environment. I am setting up the environment on a Windows 10 64-bit PC to develop a Java ME Embedded 8 application for use on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I have set up the Raspberry Pi successfully.  However, when setting up the development environment on my Windows PC, Netbeans fails to detect the platform.

I have installed:

- Java SE Development Kit 8u221
- Java ME SDK 8.3
- Netbeans 8.1

I have also tried

- Java SE Development Kit 12.0.2, and 8u152
- Java ME SDK 8 and 3.4
- Netbeans 8.0.2 and 8.2

I have tried downloading and installing the sun java wireless toolkit. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling in many different orders with different combinations of versions. I have tried changing permissions. I have tried installing the Netbeans plugins automatically and manually in multiple ways and orders. I have also tried setting it up as a Custom CLDC Platform Emulator multiple times but every time Netbeans crashes and breaks, and I have to uninstall it and reinstall again.

I have also checked the release notes of the Java ME SDK 8.3 and it says it supports Windows 10 64-bit.

Screenshot of platform set up steps taken:

- Step one of platform set up:

  [image: Step one]
- Step Two of platform set up:
  [image: Step two]
- Step Three of platform set up:
  [image: Step three]

I know that there are many similar questions on here, but I can assure you I have read all of them, tried their solutions and I have still not found a solution.

Any help any of you can offer me would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION: Downloaded an older version of the JDK - jdk 8u11. Then I directed my Java ME SDK 8.3/bin java file to that version instead.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Netbeans 8.0 not detecting Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717322/how-to-fix-netbeans-8-0-not-detecting-java-me)

Comment: [1] This question can't be resolved as it stands; more information is needed. As a start, note that your third screenshot names a log file containing further details of the problem. Update your question with the content of that log which gets written as a result of attempting to add Java ME as a platform in NetBeans. There will probably be an exception and a stack trace. [2] I gave [a very detailed answer on this issue that worked for someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727438/2985643). Have you tried that approach? If so, update your question with the problem you encountered.

Comment: I think your problem is in your first screenshot, where you select radio button _"Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator"_ instead of _"Custom Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator"_. The error message in your third screenshot explicitly tells you to do that: _"To use the platform inside the IDE you will need to configure it manually as a **Custom Java Micro Edition Platform Emulator**"_

Comment: As pointed out I have already tried to configure manually as a custom emulator, unfortunately this crashes and freezes my Netbeans. Upon looking more into the log file and some further reading of some other forums I read that there is an issue with the jdk version I was using. The solution being, downloading an older version of the jdk - jdk 8u112 - and directing my Java ME SDK 8.3/bin java file to that version instead. This fixed the platform detection error. However my device manager still crashes but I am working to fix that now. Thank you for your help.