# Installing J2ME plugins in NetBeans 12.4

Tags: netbeans, java-me, netbeans-plugins

I downloaded J2ME plugins from here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javame-sdk-downloads.html

I can't install the plugins, this is the error:

```
Some plugins require plugin Java Profiler Core to be installed.
The plugin Java Profiler Core is requested in version >= 2.1.1 (release version 2) but only 3.41 (of release version different from 2) was found.

The following plugins are affected:
     Java ME SDK CPU Profiler Snapshot Viewer
     Profiler (Java ME Projects Support)
```

Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a couple of basic points:

- I don't know whether Java ME works with NetBeans using a JDK version > 8 so I first set the default platform for NetBeans to JDK 8. This step may not be necessary, but it definitely works.
- Do not download the NetBeans plugins from the Oracle page you linked to. Instead, use the approach detailed below to use older plugins which are compatible.

In NetBeans 12.4:

- Go to **Tools > Plugins > Settings** and click **Add** to add `http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz` as an *Upgrade Center*, then check the **Active** column for its entry.
- Click the **Available Plugins** tab. You should see four entries for *Java ME*. Click the **Install** checkbox for all four, then click the **Install** button to install those plugins:
  [image: InstallMEPlugins]
- Next download **oracle-jmesdk-8-0-rr-win32-bin.exe** from the Oracle page you linked to, then run the downloaded executable to install the Java ME SDK to a location of your choice (if you haven't already done that).
- Add the ME JDK you just installed as a Java Platform within NetBeans using **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**. The exact steps are detailed in [the update at the end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727438/2985643) to [How to fix Netbeans 8.0 not detecting Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54717322/2985643).

So Java ME SDK has been added as a *Java Platform*, and the older *Java ME...* plugins have been installed. The final step is to verify that you can now use the Project Wizard to create a Java ME Embedded Application in NetBeans 12.4:

- Select **Files > New Project...** and you should see a new entry in the list of *Categories* list titled **Java ME Embedded**. In the *Projects* list there will be a single entry titled **Java ME Embedded Application**:
- Click **Next >**, and you should see a screen similar to this:
  [image: JavaMEProject]
- Set the **Project Name** field, and any other fields, as necessary.
- Finally, click **Finish** to create the **Java ME** project.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to install the J2ME platform, but I don't was able to install the plugins, they are not shown to me.
This is what I did:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11fcac4bKoK4ggLbie0XUqr2_kgJFregW/view?usp=sharing
and here they are not shown to me:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-WEFb8UwYPpTUegt9eK71kFsGcCfsV2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @יהונתןאלברט Perhaps the plugins are already installed? If so, they would not be shown on the _Available Plugins_ tab. You can check this by selecting the _Installed Plugins_ tab, then checking the _Details_ checkbox. Do you see the four _Java ME_ plugins listed under the _Name_ column? Also, if you select **File > New Project...** do you see _Java ME Embedded_ listed as an option?

Comment: I succeeded! Thank you!!